# How to enable an Apple ID login within an app?

Tags: xcode, authentication

I'd like the user to do an apple id login before he can access some features. This is mainly for parental controls.

Can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple supports OAuth to do this, where it can bring up apple login screen and proceed with valid credentials. [Ref link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accounts/Reference/ACAccountCredentialClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)

However I wonder if the use case is not that strong to implement OAuth which is a complex process.

You can have your own server where you can request user to authenticate to access some features but not with apple credentials.